# Android Ide Keyboard is typing backwards

Tags: java, android, xml, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I ran into a problem just recently by mistake, I am typing on my keyboard and the codes are going backwards instead of forward then i open notepad to check if it's affecting the whole laptop but when typing in notepad, my codes were moving normal i.e from left to right

Comment: See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/text-direction.html

Comment: Yeah thanks.... But from that page, do you know where i can find the View menu before clicking on BiDi Text Direction

Comment: The main menu in Android Studio/Intellij at the top: [File, Edit, **View**, Navigate, Code, etc.]

Comment: Thanks dear i really appreciate... Problem solved already